# Create a graph for S&P 500 index in jquery

Tags: jquery, charts, finance

I don't have knowledge of finance and I'm working on a project for portfolio optimizer.
I want to make chart for statement given below, in jquery for my webapp:
Example SPY belongs to US equity markets, GLD belongs to Commodities. If you have 60% in SPY and 40% in GLD it will show 60% US equity and 40% commodities. The graph will show the performance of both combined. On top of the graph we will show a benchmark (to compare such as S&P500)

The chart will look like this:
[Reference chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXV4j.png)

Any kind of help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Plotly library could be used to render your graph, if you have the data. Read more here: https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started/#hello-world-example

Comment: The main problem is I don't have data. If will get data, then there will be no problem to me to show it in graph.

Comment: You can download it here for upload in your DB : https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/SP500/downloaddata